# Is there a way to get battery info (status, plugged in, etc) without reading a proc/sys file on linux?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, battery, acpi

I want to get information about the battery in C on linux. I *don't* want to read or parse *any* file! Is there any low-level interface to acpi/the kernel or any other module to get the information I want to have?

I already searched the web, but every question results in the answer "parse /proc/foo/bar". I really don't want to do this because I think, low-level interfaces won't change as fast as Files do.

best regards.

Comment: If you think about it, /proc is a kernel interface to userland

Comment: On Unix, and specially on Linux, files (or pseudo-files) are the normal way to get information. I'm not convinced you should search something else.

Comment: might be better to ask here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for UPower: http://upower.freedesktop.org/

This is a common need for both desktop environments and mobile devices, so there have been many solutions over time. For example, one of the oldest ones was `acpid`, which is pretty much obsolete now.

While I'd recommend using a light-weight abstraction like UPower for code clarity reasons, the files in `/proc` and (to some extent) `/sys` are considered part of the Linux kernel ABI, which means that changing them is generally frowned upon.

Comment: This looks nice for me. Also because I do not want to include other C code in mine (for example your upower solution). So, this way seems to be the only easy one for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The /proc filesystem does not exist on a disk. Instead, the kernel creates it in memory. They are generated on-demand by the kernel when accessed. As such, your concerns are invalid -- the `/proc` files will change as quickly as the kernel becomes aware of changes.

Check [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/proc-fs.html) for more info about `/proc` file system.

In any case, I don't believe there's any alternative interface.